# Can not import a certificate in JVM from keytool

Tags: java, cmd, keytool

I have pasted a certificate file (i.e. tfs.cer) in the folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\security
```

I am using this command to import the certificate

```
keytool -import -alias tfs -keystore  C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\security\cacerts  -file tfs.cer
```

on executing this I am getting this

[image]

Please help me , why this command in not getting executed properly. Thanks

Comment: Filenames/Paths in windows command prompt containing spaces must be enclosed in double quotes: `... "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\security\cacerts" ...`

Comment: and what about the path for the certificate? should I just add the file name (-file tfs.cer)  or the whole path to the file (-file "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\security\tfs.cer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape whitespaces in path parameter of keystore

Comment: that worked. Thanks :). But now I am getting file not found

Comment: keytool error (likely untranslated): java.io.FileNotFoundException: tfs (The sys
tem cannot find the file specified.)

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean with "escaping"

Comment: @Gyro, removing spaces, i.e. Program Files (x86) will become ProgramFiles(x86)

Comment: @GyroGearless, you can escape whitespaces with a caret (^) sign.

Comment: @roophie: what about the path for the certificate? should I just add the file name (-file tfs.cer) or the whole path to the file (-file "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\security\tfs.cer")

Comment: @Ayush if you are in this folder "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64\jre\lib\security", -file parameter should find tf.cer but if not, just use the absolute path.

Comment: Never hardcode the `Program Files (x86)` directory. Use `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.